# ios - when going back to a screen that hides/shows elements, button is not placed right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I have a screen with a toggle. If yes is selected, then some elements are shown, and if no is selected then the elements on the form are hidden and the submit button is moved up so that there is no white space where some elements once were.

Here is the code for that:

```
- (IBAction)privacy:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    if (self.privacySwitch.on)
    {
        nameField.hidden = NO;
        emailField.hidden = NO;

        nameLabel.hidden = NO;
        emailLabel.hidden = NO;

        CGPoint pt = buttonProperty.center;
        pt.y += 135;
        buttonProperty.center = pt;

    }
    else
    {
        nameField.hidden = YES;
        emailField.hidden = YES;

        nameLabel.hidden = YES;
        emailLabel.hidden = YES;

        CGPoint pt = buttonProperty.center;
        pt.y -= 135;
        buttonProperty.center = pt;
    }
}
```

It all works.  The problem I am having is that if the user enters the form, goes to the next screen, but then presses the back button, all the elements appear as they used to, but the button is where it originally was despite the other elements still hidden and it looks weird.
Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Would anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: If u wrote any code in Viewdidload do copy and paste in to ViewwillAppear

Comment: Are you using a nib or storyboard?  If so, is autolayout turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Write code in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
}
```

check whether in editing mode and change UI accordingly.

Comment: what is viewWillAppear? Sorry I am not familiar.

Comment: It is the method which is called when view comes to foreground. Like viewDidLoad is called when view is loaded first time.

Comment: I am not sure what that will do. I already know that it will appear incorrectly :) the problem is that I don't know how to change the ui accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code so that I can tell you the exact problem?
Most probably you have written code for changing UI in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear()
{

}
```

method. You need to cut-paste it in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad()
{

}
```

method.

You seem to be newbie. If you don't know where these methods are then in view controller for this code press `ctrl+F` to search and search for these method names.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using auto layout? As others have said, please post the code in your `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. Did you place the button programmitcally or just using interface builder? I've had issues with things not loading right on the device even though they are placed correctly in IB. I just deleted it and re-added and all was well. Please post back with more details and I will edit my answer.